# How do I combine all my notifications into one expandable one in API 14+?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

My app might have multiple notifications for different events and instead of showing 4 notifications, I want to combine them like GMail does. How do I do this? Is this possible in API 14 or was this added in JellyBean?

Answer (score 3):

The large notification you're thinking of (specifically [InboxStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html)) was added in Jelly Bean, but there's nothing stopping you from aggregating multiple pieces of information in a single notification on earlier versions of Android (you just won't be able to fit as much in). Use NotificationCompat to create a Notification that has a nice `bigContentView` for JB+ devices and a more concise summary version on older devices.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and see if that fits what I'm looking to do.